# eclipse context menu reference hierachy,what does it mean?

Tags: java, eclipse

I noticed that eclipse context menu about "reference" has three sub options:

workspace, project, and hierarchy.

so, what the hierarchy in here means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that it will search for references to the field or method in the hierarchy of the class, i.e. in all superclasses and subclasses, recursively.